# JavaScript class prototyping using module pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module, this, prototype

I was searching of way to define a class in JavaScript. I came up with hybrid Module and Prototype pattern, but not sure if I don't miss something. Basically I wanted to use 'this' keyword. Example:

```
var A = function()
    {
    this.x = 10;
    };

A.prototype = (function()
    {
    function privatePrint()
        {
        alert("Printing from private! x:" + this.x);
        }
    this.print = function()
        {
        privatePrint.call(this);
        };
    return this;
    }).apply(A.prototype);

var a = new A();
a.print();
```

Return value is just for readability - A.prototype can be used in the beginning.

Patterns I also tried:

- Module : 'new' keyword cannot be used.
- Prototype, Revealing Prototype :
  no extending if private functions declared in prototype declaration
  (public methods returned by object)

Is my approach acceptable?

Comment: I don't see how that approach is useful...What's the advantage? It just seems confusing. Why not just `A.prototype = { ... }`..

Comment: After setting prototype to and object same operation cannot be used to extend it.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Public**

function Constructor(...) {
   this.membername = value;
}
Constructor.prototype.membername = value;

**Private**

function Constructor(...) {
   var that = this;
   var membername = value;
   function membername(...) {...}

}

Note: The function statement

function membername(...) {...}

is shorthand for

var membername = function membername(...) {...};

**Privileged**

function Constructor(...) {
   this.membername = function (...) {...};
}
```

Comment: I'm trying deliberately avoid declaring methods in constructor because they are created for every new instance.

Comment: More info: http://blog.thejit.org/2010/10/10/javascript-class-performance/
Private function in constructor performance is ~98% worse

Answer (score 0):

It's over two years since you asked, but in Googling for a similar approach I ended up here. I don't see a drawback to your implementation other than (since you are essentially asking for an opinion) it seeming a tad confusing why you are passing the prototype in as an import on the IIFE.

Otherwise, what you've got looks very similar to other "standard" implementations of the **"Revealing Prototype Pattern"** which I've seen essentially as such:

```js
(function (NS) {

    'use strict';

    // constructor for the Person "Class", attached to your global namespace
    var Person = NS.Person = function (name) {
        // set properties unique for each instance
        this.name = name;
    };

    // may not be necessary, but safe
    Person.prototype.constructor = Person;

    // private method
    var _privateMethod = function() {
        // do private stuff
        // use the "_" convention to mark as private
        // this is scoped to the modules' IIFE wrapper, but not bound the returned "Person" object, i.e. it is private
    };

    // public method
    Person.prototype.speak = function() {
        console.log("Hello there, I'm " + this.name);
    };

    return Person;

})(window.NS = window.NS || {}); // import a global namespace

// use your namespaced Person "Class"
var david = new NS.Person("David");
david.speak();
```

There is also a similar module pattern, the structure of which might be **more like the "Class" implementation** you are after:

```js
(function (NS) {

    'use strict';

    // constructor for the Person "Class", attached to your global namespace
    var Person = NS.Person = function (name) {

        // reset constructor (the prototype is completely overwritten below)
        this.constructor = Person;

        // set properties unique for each instance
        this.name = name;
    };

    // all methods on the prototype
    Person.prototype = (function() {

        // private method
        var _privateMethod = function() {
            // do private stuff
            // use the "_" convention to mark as private
            // this is scoped to the IIFE but not bound to the returned object, i.e. it is private
        };

        // public method
        var speak = function() {
            console.log("Hello there, I'm " + this.name);
        };

        // returned object with public methods
        return {
            speak: speak
        };
    }());

})(window.NS = window.NS || {}); // import a global namespace

// use your namespaced Person "Class"
var david = new NS.Person("David");
david.speak();
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/dgowrie/24fb3483051579b89512